# What is the most formal, polite and expressive way of saying 'Thank You'?

Tags: vocabulary, phrase-meaning, formal-language

Is there anything else other than 'thank you' to show gratitude in a polite, formal way to my professor at college?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My experience is that explaining specifically what you appreciate is the most expressive way to say "thank you". Any phrase that you could use in more than one situation will have about the same impact as a simple "thank you". This is true for both written and spoken appreciation.

For example,

> Thank you for helping me outside of your normal office hours to accommodate my work schedule. Your generosity with your time really helped me.

is much more meaningful than

> Thank you for all that you've done for me.

Answer (score 6):

There are many, many ways of saying thank you. A few formal examples are:

> - I'd like to express my sincere gratitude for...
> - I'm most grateful.
> - I'm very much obliged.

A bit less formal, but still not informal:

> - I'd like to thank you for...

Or simply:

> - Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

It could be like HIGHLY OBLIGED ! OR  HIGHLY PRAISED !

Comment: It would be better if you answered with what it could be, not what it could be like.

Comment: It would be much more helpful to give a specific phrase which the someone can use. What is s/he supposed to say? "OR HIGHLY PRAISED!" I don't even know what that means.