# Thanks for your *arduous* help

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrase-request

When I wrote down "*Thanks for your arduous help*", I thought I've chosen the proper word to convey the correct meaning, unrealized of the problem until it was pointed out to me:

> *arduous* is the wrong word; I think you mean extensive or comprehensive (or possibly detailed) in this case. They are similar, but arduous would be used for the process of producing help, not for the help-output.

Yes, I did mean to express extensive, comprehensive and detailed, but from the translated meaning, none of them mean the same level as *arduous*. I.e., none of them is as powerful as what I want to express. So,

- Why I can't say "*arduous help*" in this case? I still want to know that fine difference.
- What are the proper words for this, emphasizing on the "*excessive*" part? The only thing come to the top of my head is "*zealous*", but I want avoid it because it is most often used in a negative way. Oh, oh, "*tremendous*" is one, but that only stressed on the "big help" part, not on the part that the other person went overboard to help me.

Thanks

Comment: I think **arduous** means toilsome, very difficult, hard to achieve, I would use **your thorough help**

Comment: This isn't an exact answer, but you might find it helpful: http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/57922/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[arduous](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/arduous) has quite strong negative connotations: it is a word that you would use about a **task**, but not about a person's **contribution** to completing the task. It means **difficult, needing a lot of effort and energy**.

> When the land rover broke down, we had an **arduous** trek to get back to base.
>
> His duties are **arduous** and require a great deal of bending, squatting, reaching and lifting.
>
> He had almost completed an **arduous** 16-hour shift when the accident happened.

A more appropriate word would be enthusiastic. Which in this context committing a lot of [enthusiasm](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/enthusiasm) (energetic interest) to helping you.

Comment: Hmm... I thought the act of helping is a kind of task, isn't it? Ok, let me ask this way, what are the examples of normal usage of *arduous*? arduous task/work... anything else?  And not used cases as well, e.g., can I say the *arduous-effort*? thx

Comment: Yes, helping is a kind of task, but like JavaLatte says, *arduous* basically means "difficult".  You wouldn't say "Thank you for your extremely difficult help" either.  We use *arduous* to refer to a challenge someone faces, not to the work they do.

Comment: Ah, no wonder. Now I get you. Thank you both, and +1 for you both.

Answer (score 3):

The noun *help* collocates with quite a lot of adjectives, for example:

> Enormous, huge, immense, invaluable, substantial,
>   generous, much-needed.

For more collocations with the noun "help", here's [the link](http://oxforddictionary.so8848.com/search?word=help) to  a very helpful resource. And here's [the link](https://blog.udemy.com/thank-you-phrases/) to numerous thank-you-phrases.

As for the particular meaning you have in mind, I'm thinking over the possibility of using *tireless*, or *untiring*, or *constant*, or *continual*, but since English is my second language, I am not sure how it sounds to native English speakers - so, a couple of their comments is needed for you and me to be sure.

Lastly, "arduous help" does sound really weird. This adjective collocates best with such nouns as *process*, *work*, *journey*, *task*.

Comment: Thanks! upvoting! Hope others will think this is the most helpful too...

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Cardinal and @JavaLatte, thorough and enthusiastic are a good choices.

You could also just say `"Thanks for all your help"` or `"Thanks for all the help"` and that would be very natural.  At least in my country's vernacular that is what we would say.

Comment: In that case, I'd use *tremendous* instead. Please note what I'm trying to emphasize here.